# Populating cells in multiple sections for UITableView error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm confused as to what the problem/difference is with this code. In the first working example, I'm loading the table view from a custom class. This works dandy.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EventCell";
    ISEventsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:.2 alpha:.7];

    ISSingleEvent *singleEvent = events[indexPath.row];
    [cell populateWithEvents:(singleEvent)];

    return cell;
}
```

Now I want to add a second section to the table view and everything seems to be going fine until I add the conditions for cellForRowAtIndexPath. I get the error "No visible interface for 'UITableViewCell' declares the selector 'populateWithPasses:'

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"EventCell";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"FlareCell";
    NSString *identityString = @"";
    switch ([indexPath section]) {
        case 0: {
            identityString = CellIdentifier1;
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            identityString = CellIdentifier2;
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identityString];

    if ([indexPath section] == 0) {

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:.2 alpha:.7];

            ISSingleEvent *singleEvent = events[indexPath.row];

            // Error here (below) "No visible interface for 'UITableViewCell' declares the selector 'populateWithEvents:'
            [cell populateWithEvents:(singleEvent)];
        }
    } else {
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:.2 alpha:.7];
            ISFlareEvent *singleEvent = flareEvents[indexPath.row];

            // Error here (below) "No visible interface for 'UITableViewCell' declares the selector 'populateWithFlares:'"
            [cell populateWithFlares:(singleEvent)];
        }
    }

return cell;
}
```

So what am I doing wrong here? When I called "populateWithEvents" with only one section, it didn't throw an error. Now I've set up two section, each with it's own tableviewcell and it's just not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Look at the difference in how you declare/create the variable `cell` in the two chunks of code. The 1st one you properly use `ISEventsCell`. The 2nd one you don't.

Comment: @rmaddy Yep. I noticed this just seconds after I posted the question. I made the correction and it did correct the first section (no error) but the second still won't accept [cell populateWithFlares(singleEvent)];

Comment: Unless you update the code no one can help you find the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

just cast your cell like this

```
 [(ISEventsCell *)cell populateWithFlares:(singleEvent)];
```

You are trying to call `populateWithFlares:` for `UITableviewCell`. The metho is defined for `ISEventsCell`